# React Native video pause button - Class Component

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make the video stop and play without the controls, that is, with a button that does the job.

If I press it to pause or otherwise.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        paused: true
    };
}

render = () => {
const { data, isLoading, paused } = this.state;
{paused && <CustomIcon style={styles.playButton} name={paused ? "play" : "pause"} size={85} color="#E5E5E5" />}
<Video
    style={styles.player}
    source={{ uri: item.url }}
    repeat
    paused={paused}
    onTouchStart={() => this.setState({paused: !paused})}
    resizeMode="cover"
/>
```

I have problem with     **onTouchStart={() => this.setState({paused: !paused})}** it does not work.

**UPDATE**

```
        updatePause = () => {
            this.setState({'paused' : !this.state.paused})
            alert('paused')
        }

        const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.item}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                <Text numberOfLines={3} style={styles.description}>{item.description}</Text>
                {paused && <CustomIcon style={styles.playButton} name={paused ? "play" : "pause"} size={85} color="#E5E5E5" />}
                <Video
                    style={styles.player}
                    source={{ uri: item.url }}
                    repeat
                    onPress={this.updatePause}
                    paused={paused}
                    resizeMode="cover"
                />
                {Platform.OS === 'android' && (
                    <Image
                        source={{ uri: item.poster}}
                        style={styles.posterPlayer}
                    />
                )}
            </View>
        );
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html You are probably missing out on the `createRef` part. Also, you are not using props.setPaused and props.pause in your Video component.

Comment: Check out the update, please. I have problems in onTouchStart. I think I should use something like **onTouchStart={() => this.setState(!paused)}** but, it doesn't work.

Comment: When you do `console.log('paused', paused)` is it updated?

Comment: See the update of the post. I put a function to change the state and show an alert, but it doesn't work. It doesn't show alert or anything. **onPress={this.updatePause}**

Comment: With **onPress={updatePause}** I receive the alert with a value of "True" but it is always true, it does not change.

Comment: this.setState({paused : !paused}) doesn't work..

Comment: I made a simple sandbox, can you see if you follow the codes - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-web-forked-hsrr6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It changes the state perfectly, but, in the video it does not change the state paused = {paused} is an advance. Can you keep helping me? Thank you so much for taking the time.

Comment: Note: the video is in a flatlist that shows multiple videos.

Comment: It already works, but the problem I have now is that when one is played, they all play because they are in a flatlist.

Comment: u need to show your video component.